# Window instantly closing when opening compiled .exe in C

Tags: c, cmd

I have tried so many things. Running from command line, running from cmd, running with /K, putting system("pause"); getchar(); getch(); before return 0 and I simply can't get it to run. I'm writing in Notepad++, compiling in Cygwin and the window appears blank for the split second it appears (according to my screenshot, it could have been taken too early). Basically I've tried anything I could Google myself to. So I figured it must be something wrong with my code that the debugger doesn't show.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
float lt1, lt2, dmg, x;

lt1=10;
lt2=30;

    while(lt2>dmg)
    {
        while(x>0 || lt2>dmg)
        {
        dmg=dmg+x*lt1;
        x--;
        return (dmg);
        }
    x=x+0.01;
    return (x);
    }

printf("Horde factor is: %f", x);
return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate any help I can get, and I hope you will bear over with my inexperience.

Comment: `dmg` is indeterminate and therefore undefined behavior to even evaluate in your outer while-loop. My guess, its got some big-arse number larger than `lt2` and your loop is skipped entirely, but of course, it could also be buying me a latte on west-57th right now.

Answer (score 3):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code.

When you declare a local variable without assigning anything to it, its value is indeterminate. Usage of this variable will be undefined behavior until you assign a value to it.

In this case it's the `dmg` and `x` variables that causes this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of these statement :

```
 return (dmg); //this ends the code execution .. because you have returned something from main()
 x=x+0.01;
 return (x); // even this one is wrong
```

you are exiting the code there and never getting to the printf ..

there should only be one return in `main()` .. and at the end.

**More problems with your code:**

1. you don't initialise `dmg` and `x` , but you use them as parameters for while loop

   ```
   float lt1, lt2, dmg, x; // dmg,x uninitialized
   ```
2. In the outer while loop .. its an infinite loop as you don't do anything to the parameters of that loop to get out of it.
3. Like I said above .. there should be only 1 return in `main()`
4. Maybe instead of returning you should look into `break;` ( i don't know if thats what you want or not as I don't understand your code )

Comment: Thanks for helping out the newbie. I've gotten rid of the two superfluous return and I've initialized x and dmg. The idea was for the inner loop to change the value of dmg, and for the outer loop to change the value of x. That's what I thought I needed return for.